# oracle.manageddataaccess.client unrecognized in app.config c#

Tags: c#, oracle11g

We've been stuck with an issue related to adding oracle encryption settings into app.config file for our in-house C# windows application. The application uses Oracle Managed Driver (Version 4.121.2.0 and Runtime Version v4.0.30319) to connect to Oracle. Our aim is to encrypt all network communications between the application and the database. To do that, we have added the below app.config file and it is working fine on machine with Oracle Instant Client installed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
      <version number="*">
        <settings> 
           <setting name="SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT" value="REQUIRED"/>
           <setting name="SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT" value="AES128"/>
        </settings> 
      </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

When we tried on a new machine where Oracle Instant Client have never been installed, we got the following error:

Application Error: Try to reinstall the application System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section oracle.manageddataaccess.client in Cpmapp.exe.Config line 6
[Check error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PLUA.png)

We don't want to install any oracle client on this machine since we believe Oracle Managed driver (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll) should take over the connection hassle...

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: should add the xml node *in the projet(s)* config files where you use the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll, is not especially the main application's web.config